# how to set both the href and title attributes and give it a callback function at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

am learning jquery but am having a hard time figuring out how to set two attributes and give it a call back function at the same time.... i have te code to how to set multiple attributes and i have the code to how to give it a callback function but how do i pu them together in one...
**here's the code for setting multiple atrributes:**

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#w3s").attr({
      "href" : "http://www.w3schools.com/jquery",
      "title" : "W3Schools jQuery Tutorial"
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p><a href="http://www.w3schools.com" id="w3s">W3Schools.com</a></p>
<button>Change href and title</button>
<p>Mouse over the link to see that the href attribute has changed and a title attribute is set.</p>
```

**And here's the code with a callback function**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#w3s").attr("href", function(i,origValue){
      return origValue + "/jquery"; 
    });
  }); 
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p><a href="http://www.w3schools.com" id="w3s">W3Schools.com</a></p>
<button>Change href Value</button>
<p>Mouse over the link (or click on it) to see that the value of the href attribute has changed.</p>
```

***so how do i put them together?***  thanks in advanced to anyone who takes the time.

Comment: ok let me explain so i want to use the callback function from the second code into the first one and i want to keep how i set the tittle atrribute

Comment: look at my answer, I think that you were searching something like my aswer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use chaining (more about jQuery chaining here: http://www.jquery-tutorial.net/introduction/method-chaining/), like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#w3s").attr("href", function(i,origValue){
      return origValue + "/jquery"; 
    }).attr('title','Tutorial');
  }); 
});
</script>


<body>
<p><a href="http://www.w3schools.com" id="w3s">W3Schools.com</a></p>
<button>Change href Value</button>
<p>Mouse over the link (or click on it) to see that the value of the href attribute has changed.</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FHD84/

Comment: thanks for that ive actually already had a lesson on chaining guess i'll have to go back until i grasp the concept of chaining :) THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of what you were trying to do is:

1. When the button is clicked, the `<a>` tag will change its `href` to the jQuery page.
2. When that link is clicked, the original values will be reset

If this is correct, here is how I would do it:

```
//-- $(function () {...}) is shorthand notation for $(document).ready(function () {...});
$(function () {
    //-- I stored the lookup for #w3s to prevent duplicate calls to $()
    var $link = $('#w3s');
    //-- store the original attribute values using jQuery data()
    $link.data({
        'href': $link.attr('href'),
        'title': $link.attr('title')
    });
    //-- This is essentially the same as your $('button').click(), but using delegation
    $(document).on('click', 'button', function () {
        //-- update the attributes
        $link.attr({
            'href': 'http://www.w3schools.com/jquery',
            'title': 'W3Schools jQuery Tutorial'
        })
        //-- on click, reset the original values
        $link.on('click', function (event) {
            //-- event.preventDefault() will stop the link from performing its default functionality
            //-- in this case, that would be following the href
            event.preventDefault();
            //-- pull the original values from jQuery data()
            $link.attr({
                'href': $link.data('href'),
                'title': $link.data('title')
            });
        });
    });
});
```

JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/9x56L/

Note: I disabled the link in this example.  I am not sure what the context of this is, but redirecting away from the page is probably not the intended result.

Comment: thanks @RobertMesserle youre are correct but your giving me an answer that has concepts i dont understand yet  you see am just learning jquery but i kinda understand your code though :)

Comment: Ah, sorry, force of habit.  I'll add some more comments explaining what is happening each step of the way. =)

Comment: thanks really appreciate it i'll come back once i learn more about jquery and read your code again as one of my exercises :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do in this way (store the function in a variable and then assign it to attribute)

working example --> http://jsfiddle.net/HKEeB/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    var func= function(i,origValue){
      return origValue + "/jquery"; 
    };
      $("#w3s").attr({
      "href" : func,
      "title" : "W3Schools jQuery Tutorial"
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks it is a much cleaner code now i know how can i make code more readable thanks to you .. cheers man ...   i will come back when i have enough reputation points to vote this answer up :)